# Array Prototype will included in the List of the Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

I am using typescript to add in  new prototype in the Array. 
I found out that i am able to print out the prototype function in the for loop.

.ts

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    group(groupByKey: T): Array<T>;

  }
}

if (!Array.prototype.group) {
  Array.prototype.group= function<T>(this: T[], groupByKey: string): T[] {
    return group(this, groupByKey);
  };
}
```

console

```
var keys = Object.keys({a:1});
var str=""
    for (var k in keys) { 
        console.log(k)
    }
```

The console output is

```
0 
group
```

is it possible to print out the value in array instead of prototype value. 
But prototype can function well too.

Comment: What is the JavaScript code produced by TypeScript? If you define someting on the prototype of Array I don't see how this shows up in the Object.keys of an object literal and even if you did Object.keys([1]) it still should only show 0 because things on the prototype should not show up in Object.keys.

Comment: tsc 

The Javascript code is

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var a= require("./a");
if (!Array.prototype.group) {
    Array.prototype.group= function (groupByKey) {
        return a.group(this, groupByKey);
    };
}

Comment: I made a mistake, for ... in will list all enumerable properties and Object.keys({}) will return an array that has group on it's prototype as enumerable (by default). So Grassator's answer could work or you could use for ... of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the function name because it is defined as enumerable property. You can change how you define it to fix this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "group", {
  value: function<T>(this: T[], groupByKey: string): T[] {
    return group(this, groupByKey);
  },
  enumerable: false, // <-- important part
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
});
```